# How to use where not in

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

| Customer | Product | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | 1 |
| A | 234 | 0 |
| A | 345 | 0 |
| B | 456 | 1 |
| C | 567 | 1 |

So I tried to write a query to return value as customers B and C

```
select customer from table 
where customer not in (select customer from table where count = 0)
```

However, I didn't get a return for this query. I want to get results from the query is customer B and C not customer A

Is there a way to fix it? I use an Oracle database

Comment: what exactly you want in the result? can you add sample result?

Comment: Sorry for misread, I want the result will be customer B and C.

Comment: please share your result here in your query return only B and C customer.

Comment: It appears your query already works, if you replace table name `TABLE` and column `COUNT` with valid names (TABLE and COUNT being reserved as SQL language keywords). [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c88bb27d3e5bf62a5a2f6b6fea18587)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (customer, product, cnt) as
  2    (select 'A', 123, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 234, 0 from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 345, 0 from dual union all
  5     select 'B', 456, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 'C', 567, 1 from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select customer
  9  from test
 10  group by customer
 11  having min(cnt) > 0;

CUSTOMER
----------
B
C

SQL>
```

Comment: OP is looking for an example on how to use `WHERE NOT IN`. Assuming that they will use the same table is not correct coz they may use other tables for the condition.

Comment: @rhemmuuu, sometimes people "suggest" solution (such as "NOT IN" in this case), but - from my point of view - it is the final result that counts. It is a simple task to use NOT IN  with query I suggested, but - why would you want to do that? To query the same table twice (instead of only once) and make it *worse*? Thank you for your comment; let's see what the OP says.

Comment: I know your solution is correct coz that's what I would do also, assuming that same table will be used for the condition.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks for your help, this is one way to use it. I will look into my problem to see it's applicable!